# Low voltage relay to control ESC from Arduino

Tags: arduino, relay, motor-controller

I have an ESC controlled by Pixhawk (a flight controller which produces a PWM). In case of emergency I need to stop the ESC by inputing it a PWM lower than 50%. Opening the circuit will not work as the ESC will continue to run 3s.
I then chose to use an relay controlled by the arduino which selects the input to the ESC between the output of the Pixhawk and the output of the arduino (which produces the 50% PWM).

Do you think it is a good design? Do you a any advice of a relay I could use? The PWM voltage is 5V and current is <40 mA.

Comment: Would PWM of 0% work for you?

Comment: Does your FC or TX not have failsafe of some sort already  If you have 5VDC like from a BEC a 5VDC signal/comms relay would be a sensible choice for a relay.

Comment: @Majenko No, the ESC continues to run during 3s and then turns off. That's why I can't use a transistor

Comment: Relays tend to be unreliable when switching low current signals. Why can't you use a logic gate?